# Python giving index out of range when reading tabular data file

Tags: python, list

For an assignment, I have to write code in Processing to read from a tabular data file. Each line of the file looks like `"Name, 242, 353, 5325, 35352"`, so the list should have five items, and if I print it, I see all five. But when I try to do `x = data[1]`, it gives me the index out of range error. Here's my code:

```
f = open('popdata.txt', 'r')

for line in f:

    data = line.rstrip('\n')
    data = data.split(',')


    city = data[0]
    x = int(data[1])
    y = int(data[2])
    old = float(data[3])
    new = float(data[4])
```

**Edit:** If I do

```
 print(data)
```

it prints:

```
"['Halifax', '447', '349', '220', '320']"
```

If I do:

```
print(city)
```

it prints:

```
Halifax
```

But if I do anything with index 1 or higher, it doesnt work?

**Edit:** I added the line `if len(data) == 5:` after splitting and it works now!

Comment: Can you please show us the result of a `print(data)` after spliting?

Comment: Does your file maybe end with an empty line?

Comment: @schwobaseggl but he is stripping the new line.

Comment: @MohitMotwani an empty line `.rstrip('\n').split(',')` results in the list `['']` which has only one element.

Comment: But he hasn't shown the output yet. How do you know?

Comment: if I do print(data), it prints "['Halifax', '447', '349', '220', '320']". If I do print(city), it prints Halifax. But if I do anything with index 1 or higher, it doesnt work?

Comment: That's because it's returning only one string.

Comment: Shouldnt data.split(',') separate it into five separate strings?

Comment: The code shown works for me when I feed the for loop a list of strings formatted as the one you show: lines = ["Name, 242, 353, 5325, 35352", "Name2, 2242, 2353, 25325, 235352"]. So I assume that @Guimoute hit the nail on the head and the file contains blank lines - maybe only the last one in the file, if it ends with a return (\n)

Comment: @planetmaker schwobaseggl said it first ;)

Comment: How do I fix blank lines

Comment: check for the length after the split of data before you continue processing and accessing them: `if len(data) <= 1: continue`

Comment: The print you show is when it works, it would be interesting to see the printed value right before you have an error. To fix blank lines you can either be more careful at file creation, or add support for emply lines in your code. Does your assignement precise which way we should go with that?

Comment: We didn't talk about empty lines or anything in class. The first two lines after the for loop are directly from an example we did in class, so I assumed it would work. I tried using only those first two lines after the for loop and doing print(data[3]), for example, and it worked exactly the way it should (it printed 220). But doing x = int(data[1]) is where I get the out of range error.

Comment: @planetmaker I slightly modified your suggestion to if len(data) == 5: and it worked! Thank you everyone for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

### You can try `if else` condition on that particular index to handle exception

```
f = open('popdata.txt', 'r')

for line in f:

    data = line.rstrip('\n')
    data = data.split(',')


    city = data[0] if data[0:] else "" #inside ""(double quotes) add any value you want to return in case data is not available.
    x = int(data[1]) if data[1:] else ""
    y = int(data[2]) if data[2:] else ""
    old = float(data[3]) if data[3:] else ""
    new = float(data[4]) if data[4:] else ""
```